# Getting json datas - jquery

Tags: jquery

i cannot get the json datas via

```
     jQuery.parseJSON(myArr);
              $.each(myArr, function(key, value) { 
  alert(key + ': ' + value); 
});
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the return of the parseJSON method.

```
jQuery.parseJSON(myArr);
```

should read

```
myArr = jQuery.parseJSON(myArr);
```

otherwise, you are passing a string into the $.each method.